# Is the remote debugger from VS2010 compatible with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Is the remote debugger from VS2010 compatible with VS2008?
That is, can connect from visual studio 2008 to a machine running the remote debugger installed by VS 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 90% no, the debugger in VS2010 was changed pretty dramatically.  I got slapped any time I tried to mix and match, although I never tried it with the remote debugger.

That half hour you waited for this answer should have been enough to explore the 10% chance?  Let us know what you found out, that's sorta the point of this web site.

Answer (score 1):

It tried it, no go with VS2010 remote debugger and it worked instantly with the VS2008 remote debugger...
Hopefully, it works the other way around. I will post when I find out.